Inquiry Regarding Ubuntu 24.04 Support for Sapphire Rapids Processors
I am writing to inquire about the compatibility of Ubuntu 24.04 with Sapphire Rapids processors. Could you please confirm whether this version of Ubuntu supports these processors?

Does this answer your question? Will my device work with Ubuntu?

Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "Shopping or Hardware Recommendations" are off-topic.  Ubuntu Forums allows those sort of opinion based questions; as this is Q&A support site requires a problem (question) to be solved (answer).

Tempted to -1 for lack of research. A trivial Search Engine query shows that the Linux kernel has included Sapphire Rapids compatibility for several years.
